# How do I check the source of an email?

Tags: linux, debian, signature, dkim

I've been setting up DKIM using [this](https://tecadmin.net/setup-dkim-with-postfix-on-ubuntu-debian/) guide and I'm trying to verify it. In step 6 it says: `In received email in our mailbox, open the source of email and search for "DKIM-Signature"`.

How do I open the source of the email to check the DKIM-signature? I'm running debian. Might be a stupid question but I can't find how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: In what language?  How do you receive the mail?  Are you using a mail-handling library?

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm using Postfix and I'm sending the mail via telnet

Comment: And what language are you writing this code in?  You should add the appropriate tag, so that experts in that language are more likely to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail -vs "Test DKIM" test_email@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

This command sends an email to test_email@gmail.com, so enter your real email and check the spam folder for the mail.

After this, open the email, click the 3 vertical dots on the right of the email and select "Show original" option from the dropdown and here you will see the DKIM signature